# Working with MarkLogic with Java client API?

Tags: java, marklogic

I working on MarkLogic data server with Java. I need to work on Dynamic web project...does any one know how to work form submission with MarkLogic data server?

Answer (score 2):

You handle form submission like you would with any Java application.  Here's a [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/).

Once you have data in Java, you can write/read/search it with MarkLogic using [Pojo Data Binding](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/binding), one of the Pojo handles like [JAXBHandle](http://www.marklogic.com/blog/io-shortcut-marklogic-java-client-api/) or [JacksonDatabindHandle](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/3.0-master/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/JacksonDatabindTest.java), or by building [XML](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/3.0-master/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/example/handle/JDOMHandleExample.java) or [JSON](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/3.0-master/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/example/handle/JacksonHandleExample.java) in Java, then [writing that with the appropriate handle](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_50917).

In general, to use [the Java Client API, please refer to the guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java).

Comment: To help your research, here are some sample projects you can examine to see how input is handled there: [Samplestack](http://developer.marklogic.com/code/samplestack), [Springboot MarkLogic Sample](https://github.com/nikos/springboot-marklogic-sample).